# How to lock a table in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, locking

Ok, so here is the background... I have a stored procedure that is performing some operations (selects, updates, inserts, etc.) on a single table. This stored procedure can/is running several different instances/iterations (not sure the proper term here) at a time.

My question is, how do I lock down the table for the entirety of the procedure so that the same procedure running as a different thread/instance/iteration (whatever the term is) has to wait in line for the first one to finish before it can begin?

If you can provide actual code snippets of the usage so I can see it used in context, that would be greatly helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the transaction can take a  table lock directly. But if you put the statements in a transaction and have each update and insert take a table lock then you should pretty much lock out any other update. But why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [transaction isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

inside your procedure and set it as your need.